# How to insert new row in the same table using while loop

Tags: php, mysqli, while-loop, html-table

I'm trying to make 3 tables, I've used this while loop,
the problem that
I didn't know how to make the loop insert the new row in the same table.
It makes new tables for each new row or just mess it up by putting  information that should appear in another table.

Please help me.

What I got:

> ```
> contract    name    cost    period
>  210         sama     20        3
>
>
> id         date    account    visit
> 2         3-jun      20        3
> ...
> contract    name    cost    period
> 200         mama     10        3
>
> id         date    account    visit
> 4          10        3         2
>
> ....
> contract    name    cost    period
> 210         ana      50        6
>
> id         date    account    visit
> 6          50        6         5
> ```

What I want:

> ```
> contract    name    cost    period
> 210         sama     20        3
> 200         mama     10        3
> 210         ana      50        6
>
>
> id         date    account    visit
> 2         3-jun      20        3
> 4          10        3         2
> 6          50        6         5
> ```

This is my code:

```
<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)):?>

 <div style="font-size:1.5rem;  padding:0px; margin:0px; position:relative; width:95%; " dir="rtl">
      <h1>contract </h1>
 <table bgcolor="#fff" align="center" width="70%" border="3" dir="rtl" style="font-size:1.5rem; ">
 <tr>

  <td>name</td>
  <td>cost</td>
     <td>period</td>



  <tr>

  <td><?php echo $row['contract_num'];?></td>   
  <td><?php echo $row['cost'];?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['bla'];?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['serv'];?></td>


   </tr>
   </table></div>


 <div style="font-size:1.5rem;  padding:0px; margin:0px; position:relative; width:95%; " dir="rtl">
  <h1>visits</h1>
 <table bgcolor="#fff" align="center" width="70%" border="3" dir="rtl" style="font-size:1.5rem;  ">
 <tr>
  <td>id</td>    

     <td>date</td>    
  <td>account</td>  
     <td>visit</td>

     <tr>

  <td><?php echo $row['id'];?></td>

      <td><?php echo $row['date'];?></td>  
          <td><?php echo $row['account'];?></td>

      <td><?php echo $row['visit'];?></td>  
     </tr>
     </table></div>


     <?php endwhile;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Read more on tables: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

`thead` - define table header. It has one row (`tr`) with your table's headers (`th`)

`tbody` - set the data for the columns. `tr` = table row, `td` = table data, or table cell

```
<table>
    <thead> <!-- define the header outside the while, it only needs to be defined once -->
        <tr>
            <th>Contract</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Cost</th>
            <th>Period</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody> <!-- in the body loop through all results and print one row for each result -->
        <?php while($row...): ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['contract'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['name'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['cost'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['period'] ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you for your notes .. it helped me
but my problem from the beginning is that i want to display all the table,, if i just end the loop first table works perfectly .. but the other tables won't show up .. unless I insert them in the loop .. and in this case, the row shows up in the wrong place.

Comment: For each table you have to get your data from the database (what you did with `mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)`) and use the structure I gave you. You have to have your loop inside the `tbody` and only there. If you want another table just copy and paste the table again, outside the first one.

Comment: If i do so .. it will give me this , am sorry im using my phone so sorry if there are any wrong spelling ,, ok ,, i got the right cells as row after the tabelhead and thats so good after that i will get the row that should appear in the other table coz the loop keep working and start over again then i will have agine the right row  ,,  its so stress full to me , i've tried alot